# How can I improve the efficiency of copying a sheet with Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am copying a sheet through different spreadsheets. The ID's are stored in Master file. It takes a lot of time. Is there any way to make this fast ?

```
function CopyOpenOrders() {
  
var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1M0rt-d8XJRaQmRuH8sSkcmJJFn2zKe-TlCVRV6u2-Yw");



 var sheet = source.getSheetByName("Open ORDERS")


 var MasterSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1m6Nap5wB3tboGCWtc3pIIRCo0o_VhKDoaBX2xdDQnKM").getSheetByName("Master List")

for (var i =3; i < 81; i++) {

var IDName = MasterSheet.getRange(i,4).getValue();

  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById(IDName);

  //var Delsheet = destination.getSheetByName('Open Orders');
 
    //destination.deleteSheet(Delsheet)

   sheet.copyTo(destination);

  var destsheet = destination.getSheetByName("Copy of Open ORDERS")
      destsheet.setName("Open Orders")
      destsheet.protect()
  destination.moveActiveSheet(2)
  
}

}
```

The results are very slow. I want a more efficient way to make this happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a little faster. But opening and closing the spreadsheet will always be a slow process.

```
function CopyOpenOrders() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ssid");
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Open ORDERS")
  const msh = SpreadsheetApp.openById("mid").getSheetByName("Master List");
  msh.getRange(3,4,81).getValues().flat().forEach(id => {
    let dss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
    sh.copyTo(dss);
    var dsh = dss.getSheetByName("Copy of Open ORDERS")
    dsh.setName("Open Orders")
    dsh.protect();
  })
}
```